# libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I was trying to compile darknet(YOLO) with Cuda and Opencv. I compiled them and there is no error but there is warning like this :

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcudart.so.7.5, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

When I try with the example from https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/, an error come out.

```
./darknet: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Below is my system

```
OS = Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
CUDA = 8.0
OPENCV = 2.4
```

Typing `nvcc -V` on terminal result with this

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
```

I installed opencv using this command like shown from http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

I did use option two from the page but during `make` process, it return the following error

```
modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/build.make:2982: recipe for target 'modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/graphcuts.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/graphcuts.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:16054: recipe for target 'modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 59%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_photo.so
[ 59%] Built target opencv_photo
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I already put the path for cuda inside `.bashrc` and reload it but the same error appears.
Below is the path for cuda inside my `.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message indicates that version 7.5 of the CUDA runtime is needed by OpenCV (i.e. it was compiled against that version of CUDA.
Your installed version of CUDA is 8.0. Adding it's library path will not help finding a suitable version for OpenCV.

Build OpenCV against CUDA 8.0, or install CUDA 7.5 and add the library directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Technically you could also try a mixed build (i.e. just adding the CUDA 7.5 library directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, preferably *after* the CUDA 8.0 path). However carrying two versions of the CUDA runtime will likely lead to problems (I've never tried), and I'd recommend against it.

Comment: I hope to not come back to reinstalling CUDA because that has been a pain in my ass because of the X server error I've encountered before. Anyway, you said to compile ooencv against cuda 8.0, is it mean that I need to compile the opencv from source?(i.e download the source file from github repository, build using `cmake` and do `make`) or there is a one command line for that?(i.e sudo apt-get install ...) Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for others who got same problem as me. I use the suggestion from daveselinger here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6677

git clone the repository and git checkout 3.1.0 with cuda 8 (refer to the link). After that just `cmake` and `make`

It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ cd /usr/local/cuda/lib64
$ $ln -s libcudart.so libcudart.so.7.5
```

There is no difference between libcudart.so.7.5 and libcudart.so.8.0.